# Scipy installation problems (no blas or lapack)

Tags: python, scipy

I tried to update the scipy library, but it failed. Then, I tried to uninstall and reinstall it. Removing the old version was simple, but the pip tool would not let me install the new version. The error message said that the blas and lapack packages were missing. I guess that this is required, but I was able to use scipy until now.

I checked the distributors' websites, but there is no simple way to install lapack or blas. I am not very experienced with manual setups, and I can't find enough information on installing it on my system. I am running 64-bit Windows 8 with Python 2.7 (from Anaconda).

P.S. There may be a simple solution or something obvious that I missed, so please be patient.

Comment: Anaconda has its own package manager called `conda`. You shouldn't need `pip` if you are on Anaconda.

Comment: I used conda, which successfully installed scipy. However, I cannot import certain sections. For example, I tried to import scipy.stats.beta, but I got an error (ImportError: No module named beta).

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I just was not calling it properly